# Как извлечь строку между определенных символов. reqexp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Есть строка

```
  /g/2559705e245a9d7faa2a4b9351d46e/?
```

Как извлечь из нее всё что находится между

```
  '/g/' и '/?'
```

?

Пробую так, но что то не то:

```
     let reg = url.match(/\/g\/(.*?)\//)[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ `.` выделяет вообще любой символ, а плюсик после него - означает "один или несколько совпадений". Если там точно не предвидятся пробелы, можно было и `(\S+)` - совпадает с любым символом, кроме пробела. А `match()` возвращает массив, у которого первый элемент - всё совпадение целиком, второй элемент - первая скобка в регулярке, потом вторая скобка, и т.п. (выражения внутри скобок называют Capture Group)

```js
let str = 'kdls/g/2559705e2 45a9d7 faa2a4b9351d46e/?56a';

console.log( str.match(/(\/g\/)(.+)(\/\?)/)[0] );
console.log( str.match(/(\/g\/)(.+)(\/\?)/)[1] );
console.log( str.match(/(\/g\/)(.+)(\/\?)/)[2] ); // <-- Нужен этот
console.log( str.match(/(\/g\/)(.+)(\/\?)/)[3] );
```

P.s. ["Шпаргалка" для регулярных выражений](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так - `\d[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Хороший сервис по регуляркам [Regex](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log("/g/2559705e245a9d7faa2a4b9351d46e/?".match('/g/(.*?)/')[1]);
```